# In Azure-DevOps, board view, column "New Items", how can I view my cards (work items) without "Show more" button? Only 3 cards, no filters

Tags: azure-devops, workitem

Although there are only three cards in the "New items" column on my Azure DevOps board, I always get an empty column with a button "Show more items".  Before, I had items here but they are all resolved and now the remaining cards are not shown automatically but I need to push the "Show more items" button every time.

I tried the filters but there are none.  Neither do I see something specific in the work items that could prevent them from being shown immediately...

Screenshot DevOps Board empty column with show more button:

[image: Screenshot DevOps Board empty column with show more button]

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the error page? What kind of Browser are you using?

Comment: It's actually no error - I'm using Edge Versie 120.0.2210.133 (Officiële build) (64-bits)

Comment: And I'm very sorry, but I don't find the functionality to add a screenshot at first sight :-)

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of page with the issue you describe in the question? (You can edit your question to add the screenshot)

Comment: Took me some time...

Comment: From the screenshot, you are using **New Boards Hubs** feature. Can you try to **disable** the new boards hubs feature in **Settings -> Preview features** and check if it can work as expected?

Comment: Refer to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/sr-cyrl-rs/azure/devops/project/navigation/preview-features?view=azure-devops

Comment: When I tried to add the boards filter, it showed the similar issue. Can you use the **×** to clear all filters and check if it can work?

Comment: Disabling new board hub view doesn't change much - clearing all filters neither because now I can see all work items from my colleagues but for my own work items, I still have to click the "Show more items" button :-)

Comment: I can reproduce the same issue based on your latest comment. Refer to my answer, the issue come from the Azure DevOps Boards itself. We need to contact the developer team to fix the issue. We can report the issue to  Developer Community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, when you disable the filter, you will see all work items from your colleagues. This means that the New Column contains many work items.

The issue will exist when applying the Boards filter.

In this case, I can reproduce the same issue.

For example:

[image]

The issue should come from the Azure DevOps Boards itself. I suggest that you can report the issue to the site: [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/report)

Azure DevOps developers will further investigate and resolve issues with Azure DevOps itself.

Here is the similar ticket:  [In "Boards", always display all cards (i.e. never display "show more items" hyperlink) if filter has been applied](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/in-boards-always-display-all-cards-ie-never-displa/759643)

This issue has been solved before, but it seems to have reappeared recently.